# Multi-Producer Single-Consumer Lazy Task Execution

Tags: multithreading

I am trying to model a system where there are multiple threads producing data, and a single thread consuming the data. The trick is that I don't want a dedicated thread to consume the data because all of the threads live in a pool. Instead, I want one of the producers to empty the queue when there is work, and yield if another producer is already clearing the queue.

The basic idea is that there is a queue of work, and a lock around the processing. Each producer pushes its payload onto the queue, and then **attempts** to enter the lock. The attempt is non-blocking and returns either true (the lock was acquired), or false (the lock is held by someone else).

If the lock is acquired, then that thread then processes all of the data in the queue until it is empty (including any new payloads introduced by other producers during processing). Once all of the work has been processed, the thread releases the lock and quits out.

The following is C++ code for the algorithm:

```
void Process(ITask *task) {
     // queue is a thread safe implementation of a regular queue
     queue.push(task);

     // crit_sec is some handle to a critical section like object
     // try_scoped_lock uses RAII to attempt to acquire the lock in the constructor
     //                 if the lock was acquired, it will release the lock in the
     //                 destructor
     try_scoped_lock lock(crit_sec);

     // See if this thread won the lottery. Prize is doing all of the dishes
     if (!lock.Acquired())
        return;

     // This thread got the lock, so it needs to do the work
     ITask *currTask;
     while (queue.try_pop(currTask)) {
          ... execute task ...
     }
}
```

In general this code works fine, and I have never actually witnessed the behavior I am about to describe below, but that implementation makes me feel uneasy. It stands to reason that a race condition is introduced between when the thread exits the while loop and when it releases the critical section.

The whole algorithm relies on the assumption that if the lock is being held, then a thread is servicing the queue.

I am essentially looking for enlightenment on 2 questions:

1. Am I correct that there is a race condition as described (bonus for other races)
2. Is there a standard pattern for implementing this mechanism that is performant and doesn't introduce race conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a race condition.

Thread A adds a task, gets the `lock`, processes itself, then asks for a task from the `queue`.  It is rejected.

Thread B at this point adds a task to the `queue`.  It then attempts to get the lock, and fails, because thread A has the lock.  Thread B exits.

Thread A then exits, with the `queue` non-empty, and nobody processing the task on it.

This will be difficult to find, because that window is relatively narrow.  To make it more likely to find, after the `while` loop introduce a "sleep for 10 seconds". In the calling code, insert a task, wait 5 seconds, then insert a second task.  After 10 more seconds, check that both insert tasks are finished, and there is still a task to be processed on the `queue`.

One way to fix this would be to change `try_pop` to `try_pop_or_unlock`, and pass in your `lock` to it.  `try_pop_or_unlock` then atomically checks for an empty `queue`, and if so unlocks the `lock` and returns false.

Another approach is to improve the thread pool.  Add a counting semaphore based "consume" task launcher to it.

```
semaphore_bool bTaskActive;
counting_semaphore counter;

when (counter || !bTaskActive)
  if (bTaskActive)
    return
  bTaskActive = true
  --counter
  launch_task( process_one_off_queue, when_done( [&]{ bTaskActive=false ) );
```

When the counting semaphore is active, or when poked by the finished consume task, it launches a consume task if there is no consume task active.

But that is just off the top of my head.

Comment: The try_pop_or_unlock method is actually a really compelling idea. How would I go about making that function atomic?

Comment: Did you implement the `queue`?  A simple thread-safe `queue` simply has a `mutex` in it -- in that case, just unlock the passed-in `lock` while still holding the `mutex` when the `queue` is empty.  For fancier thread-safe `queue`s, things get harder.

Comment: Unfortunately this implementation is the latter.

Comment: If the queue had a thread safe `size()` function or `empty()` function, would it also work to check empty() after releasing the lock. If not empty, attempt to get the lock back and start processing again?

Comment: In some memory models, yes.  I don't know how your `queue` and your `lock` memory models interact.  I also encourage you to prove that it works yourself.  X occurs after Y is the basic unit of logic in these kind of problems.  If you are messing about with multithreaded programming, you should seek to understand the memory models of your various concurrency primitives.

Comment: By memory model I assume you are referring to whether or not the `empty()` function would be reading a potentially cached variable vs. a memory read?

Comment: No.  Synchronization is about both atomicity and ordering.  I have no idea what guarantees your `queue` has.  Or your lock!